# Why would anyone buy a Pony over a Mule?

Tags: dnd-5e, mount, pricing

Here are the statistics from the **Mounts and Other Animals** Table in the DMG:

| Item | Cost | Speed | Carrying Capacity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pony | 30 gp | 40 ft. | 225 lb. |
| Donkey or mule | 8 gp | 40 ft. | 420 lb. |

The pony costs 30 gp, and can only carry 225 lb. 
The mule costs just 8 gp, and can carry 420 lb. 
Both have the same speed, 40 ft.

I'm wondering why someone would rather buy the pony, when its nearly four times as expensive, *and* can only carry about half as much weight?

I would have expected the mule to be  more expensive than the pony given these stats, not less expensive. Is there any amazing advantage of a pony I am missing?

Comment: My little princess is getting a pony, not some classless peasant mule.

Comment: I've always thought it was weird that mules are listed as "medium" given that they are in fact popular mounts for real life trail-riders. A mule is smaller than a horse but like... not *that* much smaller.  The real difference *ought* to be that a pony is correctly sized for a Small rider while a mule is not! (Also they're adorable and how dare you @Warcupine )

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Easy.  I need a pack animal and I come across a guy selling a pony.  A mule might be better on paper, but he's not selling a mule.  I could hold out until I find a mule for sale, but in the meantime I have to leave some of this sellable loot behind because it's more than I can carry by myself.  Is that actually more cost-efficient in the long run? Probably not, unless I somehow know for certain that there's a mule for sale somewhere nearby.

When looking at different options in table form like that, it's easy to think of it like a catalog or menu board.  In the real world (game world?), you have to make choices based on the limited selection that you have available, which is usually not the full menu.  In this scenario, buying the pony is a no-brainer.  Should I happen across a mule for sale later I can sell my pony for almost what I paid for it (they don't depreciate like cars), buy the mule, and end up with most of my money back.  If the difference between the pony's buy and sell price is less than the value of the additional loot it allowed you to carry, then you came out ahead.

Comment: That actually is a good reason. Our group bought a pony in Phandalin in Mines of Phandelver, because one could not buy a Donkey there, and we needed a pack animal. And my character was a cutesy Halfling Bard so Lord of the Ring cultural reasons helped. But we would have bought a mul instead had there been one on sale.

Answer (score 49):

#### The saying goes "stubborn as a mule".

You are thinking about this out of character while looking at game mechanics. Yeah, the mule is better-by-the-numbers, and if that's all you ever consider, then you will pick the mule. But this is a *role playing game*: think about this *in character*. What if I don't really *need* the extra capacity or surefootedness of a mule? Which am I going to pick? Some smelly, stubborn ass or a pretty, patient, and compliant pony? And consider the image you are projecting. Are you a band of dirty low-lifes riding mules or a party of respectable, pony-riding problem-solvers? Obviously this all depends on how your DM cares to roleplay the difference between a pony and a mule within the narrative, but it is definitely something most characters would consider when selecting a mount.

Also ponies kick harder (+4 to hit for 2d4+2 damage vs. +2 to hit for 1d4+2 damage), and are stronger, allowing them to wear better barding. The pony has 15 strength, so it can wear Splint or Plate barding without penalty, but the mule has 14 strength.

Comment: A minor note in the veins of kicking harder, ponies also have a strength of 15 (not 14) so they'd not be slowed down by barding made from splint or plate. And if you're spending 800 or 6000 gp on the barding, 30 gp for the pony is nothing

Comment: In the same idea, you could also mention the fact that there's a clear difference of image, which depending on the DM could even affect things like persuasion or other charisma-related rolls. An adventurer is definitely going to look better while riding a fancy pony than while riding a temperamental mule.

Comment: For the record, mules aren't actually stubborn, they're just much smarter than we're used to seeing in equines. They will actively refuse to do things they can tell are dangerous, or carry loads that are too heavy for them, which we sometimes read as stubborn if we don't pay attention. And sometimes they'll be jerks on purpose but that's more in the way of a prank than anything else.

Comment: Also note that historically there were saddles, including war saddles, that could fit on a pony. Selection of saddles that could fit a donkey or a mule was much more limited, if at all available. And in my limited experience ponies are much better in mountains.

Comment: @Mołot - at the Grand Canyon they use mules for people riding up/down the canyon from/to Ghost Ranch, not ponies. Impressively sure-footed animals.

Comment: @JonCuster Guess you don't have welsh mountain ponies there ;) Or mountain horses (that are a breed of Balkan Ponies). And most of fantasy settings are European-based. YMMV, breeds we have now have a thousand years of selective breeding since then anyway, so all we can do is guess, today comparisons will always be abysmal.

Comment: Is breeding big in D&D?  Because mules tend to be sterile, which might be a disadvantage for someone who'd want to breed them.

Comment: @Nat Generally speaking, most campaigns probably don't happen on timescales where the player characters would consider getting into animal husbandry, and those that do would almost certainly be keen to handwave it if it even comes up.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov unless it is breeding small animals like birds, I agree. Falconry has been the past time of a hunter of mine, in a campaign that spun over about 5 in game years.

Comment: Funny that a pony kicks harder than a mule considering the "Kicks like a mule" saying

Comment: @BillK No one who got kicked by a pony survived to coin the saying.

Comment: @DarthPseudonym  They're not actually that much smarter than horses. It's more like the difference between a dog and a cat. Horses are strongly social and will do what the leader of the herd says, even if it's difficult, dangerous, or uncomfortable. Mules are more independent with more of a "what's in it for me" attitude. As long as you make sure there is actually something in it for them they can be very well behaved indeed, and very decisive when action is needed.

Comment: "Pretty, patient, and compliant pony"...  Written like someone who has never actually *worked* with a pony...  Mules can be obstinate at times...  Ponies are downright vicious.

Comment: While I agree most player characters won’t get into breeding animals, the fact that ponies can be bred is definitely a factor in their much higher cost, and thus resale value. So another reason you might want one if you have the money is that you can be surer if being able to sell it on when you no longer need it, and possibly for closer to the price you paid for it (depending on how that’s handled at your table).

Answer (score 5):

Because she wants a pony for her 16th birthday.

---

The game tries to account for the numerous differences between ponies and mules (abilities, temperament, shape, prestige, etc) via their stats, but it does a bad job because that's not the focus of the game. Sometimes, one in-game option is clearly better than another stat-wise<sup>[1]</sup> even if that wouldn't be the case in real life.

This brings us to the real reason for the existence of the two: They both exist in real life and a character might want one for what it is, rather than for its stats. A player wanting a pony wouldn't necessarily be interested in a mule, whatever its stats.

---

1. The answer shows that this is the case for mule vs donkey.